# ASP.NET MVC HTML5 Boilerplate - Content Security Policy is killing all external scripts, even “whitelisted” ones

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-5, html5boilerplate

Current Project:

- ASP.NET 4.5.2
- MVC 5
- HTML5 Boilerplate
- Google ReCaptcha (any NuGet package, take your pick, I’ve already churned through three of them)

So it appears that anything from outside the [site I am developing](http://www.taskgenerator.ca/demo/) gets stopped, *cold*, by the Content Security Policy. Yes, there is supposed to be a Google ReCaptcha at the bottom of that form. Don’t see it? Yeah… This is *despite* things like `ajax.googleapis.com` being supposedly “whitelisted” through `FilterConfig.cs`.

When I go to my site and try to load it, I get the console error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js ("script-src http://http://www.taskgenerator.ca http://localhost:* http://ajax.googleapis.com http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com").
```

When I add `www.google.com` to the `CspScriptSrcAttribute()` inside `FilterConfig.cs`, I get the following error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20160913151359/recaptcha__en.js ("script-src http://http://www.taskgenerator.ca http://localhost:* http://www.google.com http://ajax.googleapis.com http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com").
```

When I add `www.gstatic.com` I get the following error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k=6LdHZB4TAAAAAMj_6F7h1ahYTNAjtHqRvWLj_FBx&co=aHR0cDovL3Rhc2tnZW5lcmF0b3IubG9jYWxob3N0Ojgw&hl=en&v=r20160913151359&size=normal&cb=lvhf93b5gk4z ("default-src 'none'").
```

despite having already whitelisted `www.google.com` as per above.

This is happening all the way down the &#$!%(@ rabbit hole. There doesn’t seem to be an end to it. All I want is to add a stupid ReCaptcha to the site -- how hard should that be??

I am being seriously convinced to gratuitously tear the HTML5 boilerplate from the project and go it raw/custom/default just to avoid these intractable show-stopping critical bugs.

Please tell me:

1. How to turn **OFF** CSP from within the HTML5 Boilerplate, or
2. How to correct this issue for a feature that *should* already be whitelisted (Google API).

The [HTML5 MVC Boilerplate page](http://rehansaeed.com/asp-net-mvc-boilerplate/) [provides ZERO advice](http://rehansaeed.com/content-security-policy-for-asp-net-mvc/) in this regard.

---

EDIT:

The code within my `FilterConfig.cs` was originally as such:

```
filters.Add(
  new CspScriptSrcAttribute() {
    CustomSources = string.Join(
      " ",
#if DEBUG
      "localhost:*",
#endif
      ContentDeliveryNetwork.Google.Domain,
      ContentDeliveryNetwork.Microsoft.Domain
    ),
    Self = true,
  });
```

With the constants (`contentdeliverynetwork.cs`) as such:

```
public static class ContentDeliveryNetwork {
  public static class Google {
    public const string Domain = "ajax.googleapis.com";
    public const string JQueryUrl = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js";
  }
  public static class MaxCdn {
    public const string Domain = "maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com";
    public const string FontAwesomeUrl = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
  }
  public static class Microsoft {
    public const string Domain = "ajax.aspnetcdn.com";
    public const string JQueryValidateUrl = "//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js";
    public const string JQueryValidateUnobtrusiveUrl = "//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js";
    public const string ModernizrUrl = "//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.8.3.js";
    public const string BootstrapUrl = "//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js";
  }
}
```

And even a modification to the following:

```
filters.Add(
  new CspScriptSrcAttribute() {
    CustomSources = string.Format("google.com www.gstatic.com www.google.com localhost:* ajax.googleapis.com ajax.aspnetcdn.com"),
    Self = true,
  });
```

does not help.

Comment: …Bueller? …Bueller?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome normally tells you what is being blocked as you've found. You just need to add all of the exceptions it tells you about. That said, if you want to turn off CSP, comment out the following line:

```
public static class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        AddSearchEngineOptimizationFilters(filters);
        AddSecurityFilters(filters);
        AddContentSecurityPolicyFilters(filters); // Comment this out
    }

    // ...Omitted
}
```

Comment: The problem I have is that everything circles back to google.com, which has already been white listed but is still getting blocked. Check the third error message - I am getting that even with www.google.com in the whitelist.

Comment: You added `http://www.google.com` but not `https://www.google.com`, note the 's'. You can actually add `*.google.com` to encompass both.

Comment: …and I am still getting hung up on the third error message. It is flagging www.google.com even though I explicitly added *.google.com

Comment: If you get the third URL, you will see that it's a HTML page. So you need to change the default-src to include `*.google.com`.

Comment: looks like the CSP is now killing all Google Maps abilities. Again, I have whitelisted all relevant content: `new CspDefaultSrcAttribute() {CustomSources = string.Join(" ", "*.google.com", "*.gstatic.com", "*.googleapis.com"),` and `CustomSources = string.Join(" ", "localhost:*", ContentDeliveryNetwork.Google.Domain,
     ContentDeliveryNetwork.Google.Static,
     ContentDeliveryNetwork.Google.Api,
     ContentDeliveryNetwork.Google.Ajax,
     ContentDeliveryNetwork.Google.Maps,
     ContentDeliveryNetwork.Microsoft.Domain),`

Comment: As well as adding: `public static class Google {
      public const string Domain = "*.google.com";
      public const string Static = "*.gstatic.com";
      public const string Api = "*.googleapis.com";
      public const string Ajax = "ajax.googleapis.com";
      public const string Maps = "maps.googleapis.com";
      public const string JQueryUrl = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js";
    }`

Comment: and yet for the life of me the console bitches at me with `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=2&s=mapsapi3&v3v=28.11&action=apiboot2&e=10_1_0,10_2_0&rt=main.17 (“img-src http://localhost:60459 data:”).`